# Select a specify subview swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

how can i select a subview and interact with it using swift and n subview. For now i have only 3 subviews and select 3 image with for.
But for example how can I remove the subview with tag 2 after i create it?

```
func addSubView() {
    for index in 1...3 {
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: String(index))!
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.tag = index
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.removeSubview))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: randomNumber(range: 60...300), y: randomNumber(range: 60...400), width: 50, height: 50)
        print(imageView)
        self.backgroundImageView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}

func removeSubview() {



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function `removeSubviewWithTag(_:)` that would take a tag number as a parameter:

```
func removeSubviewWithTag(_ tag: Int) {
   if let viewWithTag2 = backgroundImageView.viewWithTag(tag) {
     viewWithTag2.removeFromSuperview()
   }
}
```

And then call it as desired:

```
removeSubviewWithTag(2)
```

If you want to know if the function was able to find and remove a subview, you could make it return a discardable Bool result:

```
@discardableResult func removeSubviewWithTag(_ tag: Int) {
   if let viewWithTag2 = backgroundImageView.viewWithTag(tag) {
     viewWithTag2.removeFromSuperview()
     return true
   } else {
     return false
   }
}
```

And call it as follows:

```
if removeSubviewWithTag(2) {
  print("Removed view")
} else {
  print("unable to remove view")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add them to an array? Using tags is rarely the best solution.

```
var imageViews = [UIImageView]() 

func addSubView() {
    for index in 1...3 {
        let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: String(index))!
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.tag = index
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.removeSubview))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: randomNumber(range: 60...300), y: randomNumber(range: 60...400), width: 50, height: 50)
        print(imageView)
        self.backgroundImageView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageViews.append(imageView)
    }
}

func removeSubview(at index: Int) {
    imageViews[index].removeFromSuperview()
}
```